# How to create a view on which user can preview song posted on iTunes Store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Would it be possible to have a songs page in iPhone App where artists that have media posted on itunes can preview and then link to the purchase page (on itunes)?

EDIT:
There is an App called Roger Sanchez which shows Artist's iTunes Songs and allows people to buy those songs from iTunes Store for within the app.

Comment: is there an issue with my answer?  How come you didn't award the bounty?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've previously answered a similar question:

[Music preview from iTunes music store in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317225/music-preview-from-itunes-music-store-in-ios-app/5317371#5317371)

Basically:

You will need to get the URL's to the music preview files. One way is via the iTunes search API's. Another is via the Apple Enterprise Partner Feed.

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed.html

Once you have the URL, you can feed it to MPMoviePlayerController or MPMusicPlayerController for progressive-download/playback.

Please check the Apple guidelines for using preview links. I believe you must be an affiliate, and you must be advertising the sale of the associated song. I also believe (please check) that Apple also permits affiliates to place these preview links on web pages, alongside affiliate links to purchase the songs.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to preview the media, unless Apple provides a way to do that on the web, which you could then embed in a browser within your app.

UPDATE: if you visit the iTunes media web pages in a normal browser you can preview the media (at least for music). In the iPhone browser however, you are automatically opened into iTunes when you enter that same URL. It might be possible to use the UIWebView without being forced to jump into iTunes, but you'll need to experiment to confirm.

Also you can build a web based system that will allow you to show the art and link to the media on iTunes using links working through the iTunes affiliate program. Joining the iTunes Affiliate Program would allow you to earn some percentage on the sales bought through your links to iTunes media.

[iTunes Affiliate Program](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/)